# Listing pages having only one value for multi-value property

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I am working on wiki where every item has its own page and its means of acquiring it listed as

```
[[Is acquired::somewhere]]
[[Is acquired::somewhere else]]
[[Is acquired::some third acquisition way, really long one with some [[wiki]] links in it]]
```

The property `Is acquired` has defined type `text`.

**My primary question is:** How can I show a list of those items having assigned only one way to acquire them (ie. one `Is acquired` property-value)?

**Secondary is:** How to list those items, that have only one way to acquire them *and* this way contains some specific text?

I have read [Extension:Arrays](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays) and also [Count format](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Count_format) and [Subqueries](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Selecting_pages#Subqueries_and_property_chains) documentation, but I just can not figure it out how to put everything together.

Please note that preferably, **I would like to avoid using `Extension:Arrays`,** if it's at all possible, as this is currently not supported by wiki I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way in SMW to filter on number of property values, so you should use `Extension:Arrays` here.

Introduce new property which will be used as flag, eg. `Is only one way` with values `Yes`/`No`. On your pages (containing `Is acquired` properties) add code like this at bottom:

```
{{#arraydefine:test_arr|{{#show: {{PAGENAME}}|?Is acquired}}|,}}
{{#ifeq:{{#arraysize:test_arr}}|1|[[Is only one way::Yes]]|[[Is only one way::NO]]}}
```

This way all your pages will contain a property `Is only one way` with values `Yes` or `No` so you can filter on it:

```
{{#ask: [[Is acquired::+]] [[Is only one way::Yes]] }}
```

Will give you pages with only one value set for `Is acquired` property.